# Does the insertion sort algorithm get affected if changed from int to double?

Tags: c, sorting

So I'm have trouble with my code , and cannot figure out why...I thought the possibilty of the fact that changing from double to int might change the function since it works fine with integers.

Code:

```
 void
    do_catavg(csv_t *D, int cat, int col) {
        int i,j,k;
        int count=0,nvalues[MAXROWS];
        double category[MAXROWS],category_red[MAXROWS];
        double average[MAXROWS];
        double sum;
        printf("%s %s\n",D->labs[cat-1],D->labs[col-1]);
        for(i=0;i<D->nrows;i++){ 
            category[i]=D->vals[i][cat-1];
            printf("%f ",category[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        sort_int_array(category,D->nrows);
        printf("\n");
        distinct(category,category_red,D->nrows);
        printf("%d\n",distinct(category,category_red,D->nrows));
        for(i=0;i<distinct(category,category_red,D->nrows);i++){
            for(j=0;j<D->nrows;j++){
                sum=0;
                count=0;
                if(category_red[i]==category[j]){
                    sum+=D->vals[j][col-1];
                    count++;
                }
                average[i]=sum/count;
                nvalues[i]=count;
            }
            printf("%f  %d\n",average[i],nvalues[i]);
        }
        return; 
    }
```

Functions:

```
void
sort_int_array(double A[], int n) {
    int i, j;
    /* assume that A[0] to A[n-1] have valid values */
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
        /* swap A[i] left into correct position */
        for (j=i-1; j>=0 && A[j+1]<A[j]; j--) {
            /* not there yet */
            int_swap(&A[j], &A[j+1]);
        }
        printf("%f ",A[i]);
    }
    printf("--BReak--");
    printf("The first value is %f ",A[0]);
    /* and that's all there is to it! */
}

int distinct(double A[],double B[], int n){
    int i;
    int new=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(A[i]!=A[i+1]){
            B[new]=A[i+1];
            new++;
        printf("%f ",B[i]);
        }
    }

    return new;
}

/* exchange the values of the two variables indicated 
    by the arguments */
void
int_swap(double *p1, double *p2) {
    double tmp;
    tmp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = tmp;
}
```

Output:

```
location mintemp
18.000000 22.000000 18.000000 22.000000 18.000000 22.000000 18.000000 22.000000
18.000000 22.000000
18.000000 18.000000 18.000000 18.000000 18.000000 18.000000 18.000000 18.000000
18.000000 --BReak--The first value is 22.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 2
0.000000 0.000000 14.200000     1
0.000000 0.000000 -1.#IND00     0
0.000000 0.000000 > k 5 6
```

Please do not care about *distinct* function because it is broken at the moment. But I don't understand why the sorting array doesnt work...

PS I have full confidence that the rest of the code is fine and works, except until the sorting array.

Thank You!

Comment: The potential problem can be with using == for comparing doubles. For doubles == should be replaced with fabs(A[x]-B[x]) < precision.

Comment: @doqtor Where in this example do you see doubles being compared with `==`?

Comment: @hellowurf Can you provide the actual values that are being sorted? As it is, the sort seems to work fine: https://ideone.com/Op3UIi

Comment: @PaulRoub ups I've looked at wrong function ... but sorting algorithm has got a line: A[j+1]<A[j] which can be a problem of similar nature ...

Comment: @doqtor: It isn't a problem in sorting. You have to ensure that `a[i] <= a[i+1]`. How is an equalitiy check with tolerance going to help you? The floating-point values might be inaccurate, but they are clearly ordered. (Well, except nans.)

Comment: when asking questions, please post code that is 'short' and only exposes the problem.  All the other code clutter just makes it harder to debug the problem.  (especially since the critical struct csv_t definition was not included in the code and the posted code does not compile)   See my answer

Comment: @PaulRoub The value are shown on the output( I echoed it).

Comment: @MOehm Well, the values are originally integers. I changed them to doubles because it was a requirements. Would that create inaccurate floating-point values?

Comment: Floating-point numbers are inaccurate per se and there isn't anything you ca do about it. That doesn't mean they can't be sorted. If you have normal floats `a` and  `b`, you can always bring them in order, because `a < b` has a clear answer. (The exception here is `nan`: Comparisons where at least one of the terms is `nan` will compare as false. But since your code assumes "valid"  input, let's not open that can of worms.) All entities, for which `a < b` by some criterion has a clear answer can be sorted.

Comment: Your insertion sort should work, by the way. The intermediary output is strange, however. You sort an array of ten elements. Could you print the whole array after each `i` loop instead of just the swapped element? Is there anything else going on, unnoted macro exmansions perhaps?

Comment: @MOehm For some mysterious reason this problem is fixed....I don't know how. I ignored this and continued with the rest, tested the code looking if my other piece of code works(which failed straight up), only to find that the output of this one working fine . Thanks for the help XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code compiles cleanly,

correctly implements an insertion sort,

the same algorithm, by changing the type, can be used to sort int, etc

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct csv_t
{
    int nrows;
    double labs[10] ;
};

void sort_double_array(double *A, int n);

struct csv_t D = {10, {200.0, 100.0, 50.0, 25.0, 12.0, 6.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0}};

int main( void )
{
    sort_double_array( D.labs, D.nrows );
    return(0);
} // end function: main


void sort_double_array(double *A, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    /* assume that A[0] to A[n-1] have valid values */

    double temp;

    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        temp=A[i];
        j=i-1;

        while( (temp < A[j]) && (j>=0) )
        { // then entries need swapping 
            A[j+1] = A[j];
            j=j-1;
        } // end while

        A[j+1]=temp;
    } // end for

    printf("--BReak--");
    printf("sorted array\n");

    for( i=0; i<n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%f ", A[i]);
    } // end for
    /* and that's all there is to it! */
} // end function: sort_double_array
```

Comment: that is 'interesting'.  I ran it before posting it, and it worked correctly on my x64 system running ubuntu linux 14.04.   Oh Well.  Thanks for catching the fact that it does not run correctly on all system.

Answer (score 0):

You are using int_swap in your sorting algorithm. Use something equivalent that works on doubles. Apart from that the function sort_int_array seems to be correct.